# List Comprehensions with nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a dict of list a.
I have a max value that corresponds to the largest list in a.
I would like to create another list containing list a and add None values if the size of the list is smaller than my max value.

I have a code that works but I would like to use a List Comprehensions.

```
a = {'t': [3, 4, 2, 3], 'y': [7, 5]}

max_len = len(max(a.values(), key=len))
new_list = []
for i in a.values():
    i.extend([None] * (max_len - len(i)))
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that? Please post your best attempt, so we can help if you have any misunderstandings or anything. Keep in mind SO is not a code-writing service, and you're expected to show some effort at solving the problem yourself. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending `i`, add.

```
a = {'t': [3, 4, 2, 3], 'y': [7, 5]}

max_len = max(map(len, a.values()))  # <- Also simplified this
new_list = [i + [None]*(max_len - len(i)) for i in a.values()]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this using list comprehension.

```
a = {'t': [3, 4, 2, 3], 'y': [7, 5]}
new_list = [j for i,j in a.items()]
print new_list
```